# Babel Decorators transform, constantly get unexpected token (with react project) no matter what I try

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, package.json, transpiler

I've done a fair amount of searching through StackO trying to find an answer but I keep coming up with the same error, `unexpected token`

Whenever I use the text decorator transpile to correct the error, I still get the same problem in my component.

My error is this:

```
./src/components/pages/projectpages/dnd2/Card.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (71:0)

  69 | };
  70 | 
> 71 | @DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, connect => ({
     | ^
  72 |   connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
  73 | }))
  74 | @DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
```

and this is how I have it setup in my package.json (and I've tried Stage 1 with no success either)

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "transform-decorators"
    ]
  },
  "stage": 0,
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "date-fns": "^1.28.5",
    "dragula": "^3.7.2",
    "flexbox-react": "^4.3.3",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-css-transition-replace": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dnd": "^2.4.0",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dragula": "^1.1.17",
    "react-fa": "^4.2.0",
    "react-flexbox-grid": "^1.1.3",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-image-compare": "0.0.1",
    "react-jsonschema-form": "^0.49.0",
    "react-modal": "^1.9.4",
    "react-moment": "^0.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-toggle-display": "^2.2.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0",
    "simple-react-forms": "^1.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^1.4.6",
    "styled-props": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

What else am I missing here?

Comment: What's in your .babelrc file?

Comment: @Wazner so I'm still pretty green to React especially in setting it up, it appears there is no babelrc file in any of the corresponding folders.  This is pretty embarrassing because I'm so new at this, I thought having it in my package.json would fix that, but I assume not?  Could you please point me in the right direction on correctly setting up babelrc or is there an alternate I can do for the @ decorators that keep giving me grief?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your package.json file

```
"babel": {
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators"
  ]
},
```

should be replaced with

```
"babel": {
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ]
},
```

Bear in mind that decorators can be written as simple JS functions.

```
@DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, connect => ({
 connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
}))
```

is the equivalent to

```
DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, connect => ({
 connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
}))(YourClassName)
```

In other word, `@` symbol acts as `(YourClassName)` for whatever class that comes after the decorator.

You can read more about EcmaScript decorators [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841).

**EDIT:**

If you want to apply to or more of these you can either nest them like this

```
DropTarget(...)(DragSource(...)(YourClassName))
```

or like this

```
const withDropTarget = DropTarget(...)(YourClassName)
const withDragSource = DragSource(...)(withDropTarget)
export default withDragSource
```

or use a [compose helper](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#compose), which would allow you to write your code like this

```
const enhance = compose(
  DropTarget(...),
  DragSource(...)
)

export default enhance(YourClassName)
```

Comment: hey thanks for answering my questions and shedding some light.  So I tried both these methods and neither seemed to work **BUT** I think I'm much closer.

I now have this https://jsfiddle.net/sthig/g5pyo7ko/  

I still get an error but I think that's due to my syntax.  

My previous code looked like this: 

https://jsfiddle.net/sthig/ozrpkjom/

Any assistance you can provide from here would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @sthig this cannot be replicated in jsfiddle, because it does not allow for ES6 syntax.

Comment: @sthig token `import` is unexpected, because it's an ES6 feature.

Comment: I'm sure this won't come over formatted well, but will try.

I have this 

`
@DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, cardTarget, connect => ({
  connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
}))
@DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource, (connect, monitor) => ({
  connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
}))

export default class Card extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    connectDragSource: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    ... 
    moveCard: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };`

Comment: Since I can't post to jsFiddle (please pardon my newbiness on all this) here's how my code is structured now:

http://imgur.com/2coIxCJ

And here is how I'm trying to rewrite it but I don't know how to redo two with the @ Decorator

http://imgur.com/0bysO3g

Comment: they should start a tip service on StackO so I could give you a billion dollars for your help.  THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

To enable decorators using Babel 6 and ES6 (annotations are a draft specification of ES7), you must do the following:

Firstly, install babel support for decorators using ES6:

```
npm i -S babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
```

In case you used an old version of create-react-app for creating your app, you must also install support for decorators to react-scripts compiler:

```
npm i -S decorators-react-scripts
```

Then, modify the babelrc file to look like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```